# missing chunk number 0 for toast value 37946637 in pg_toast_2619

Tags: postgresql

Main Issue:
Getting `"ERROR:  missing chunk number 0 for toast value 37946637 in pg_toast_2619"` while selecting from tables.

Steps that led to the issue: 
- Used `pg_basebackup` from a Primary db and tried to restore it onto a Dev host.
- Did a `pg_resetxlog -f /${datadir}` and started up the Dev db. 
- After starting up the Dev db, when I query a varchar column, I keep getting:

```
psql> select text_col_name from big_table;

ERROR:  missing chunk number 0 for toast value 37946637 in pg_toast_2619
```

This seems to be happening for most varchar columns in the restored db.

- Has anyone else seen it?
- Does anyone have ideas of why it happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

pg_resetxlog is a bit of a last resort utility which you should prefer not to use. Easiest way to make a fully working backup is to use pg_basebackup with the `-X s` option. That is an uppercase X. What this does is that basebackup opens two connections. One to copy all the data files and one to receive all of the wal that is written during the duration of the backup. This way you cannot run into the problem that parts of the wal you need are already deleted.

Comment: Good point on not using pg_resetxlog and use of -X. We used the resetxlog as it was a dev env.  and didn't have the wal files from prod. And we didn't care abt any active transactions during the backup. Anything we can do to make this restored db usable?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things since by original question. I can confirm that the source of my error "ERROR: missing chunk number 0 for toast value 37946637 in pg_toast_2619"  was doing a pg_resetxlog during the restore process.

I re-did the restore today but this time, applied the pg_xlog files from Primary using recovery.conf. The restored db started up fine now and all queries are running as expected.